# Time trigger function with CosmosDB inputs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created a time trigger function in azure functions and Added a CosmosDB input as shown below.

[image]

Below is the .csx file

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, string[] inputDocument, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    // string [] = bindings.inputDocument;

    DocumentClient client;
}
```

How to get the input documents from cosmosDb into this csx file?

I am not familiar with C#, in javascript we will use `var Data = context.bindings.DataInput;`
How to do the same in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like the below snippet

```
public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, IEnumerable<dynamic> documents)
    {
        foreach (var doc in documents)
        {
            // operate on each document
        }
    }
```

More examples in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#input---c-script-examples)

Questions from comments

> If we have more than one cosmos Db input do we need to add as below ?

No if even if you have more than one inputs the `IEnumerable<dynamic> documents` is used. And you can iterate the list.

> How to add if we have a cosmosDB output ?

The `out object` is used in this which points to your binding.

```
public static void Run(string myQueueItem, out object employeeDocument, ILogger log)
    {
      log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

      dynamic employee = JObject.Parse(myQueueItem);

      employeeDocument = new {
        id = employee.name + "-" + employee.employeeId,
        name = employee.name,
        employeeId = employee.employeeId,
        address = employee.address
      };
    }
```

More information on [Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output---c-script-examples)

Comment: Just for clarification,  
1. If we have more than one cosmos Db input do we need to add as below ?
`public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, IEnumerable<dynamic> documents01, IEnumerable<dynamic> documents02)`  
2. How to add if we have a cosmosDB output ? Is it same as we add cosmosDB input like `IEnumerable<dynamic> documentsOut` ?

Comment: @Antony i have updated the answer please take a look